# Token Introspect API not working after changing the regex restriction for username in WSO2 IS 5.9.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity server and using email as username from following documentation-
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/

Then while performing a sign-up ie create users using SCIM2 APIs with email more than 30 characters i was getting the following error-

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "scimType": "invalidValue",
    "detail": "31301 - Username test1233.admin@motioneducation.com is not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, ^[\\S]{3,30}$",
    "status": "400"
}
```

Then to fix this i added this regex expression in deployment.toml file in user store-

```
[user_store]
username_java_script_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
username_java_regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'
```

This change fixed my sign-up problem but the token generated by performing login using wso2 /oauth2/token API is giving 401 unauthorized in /oauth2/introspect API?

Please Help........?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have enabled email as username, then you need to use the **email username** in the authorization header also. A sample curl command is given below.

> curl --location --request POST
>   'https://{host_name}:{port}/oauth2/introspect' 
>   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
>   --header 'Authorization: Basic {base64encode(emailusername:password)}'
>   --data-urlencode 'token={access_token}'

**Sample request**

> curl --location --request POST
>   'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect'
>   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
>   --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW5Ad3NvMi5jb206YWRtaW4=' 
>   --data-urlencode 'token=47f65812-c5fb-3f90-b5c0-3bbc3603578f'

401 unauthorized error comes only if you are sending invalid credentials. So please check whether you are sending valid **emailusername and valid password** in authorization header

Comment: I am facing a similar issue where i am able to  signup new users to db. Its getting saved in my Carbon Database . I am able to login using previously created super admin user , but not able to login using a new user . The request headers and args passed is similar and only change is in username and password fields. I have posted the query in stackoverflow. If you can , could you please check my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150158/provided-authorization-grant-is-invalid-error-while-trying-to-login-a-dockeriz?noredirect=1#comment106389486_60150158