# 'Provided Authorization Grant is invalid' error while trying to login a dockerized application using wso2

Tags: docker, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have dockerized our Angular application which have been using **WSO2** as API manager . After doing the configurations, i was able to run the application successfully and able to hit all existing api's. The only issue arises when i tried to use **oath2/token** api for performing login operation of our customer . Even though, the same code was used to perform authentication earlier(before dockerization) without any issues,now i am getting error as

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Provided Authorization Grant is invalid"
}
```

Token generation api for login :

```
https://<myapplicationurl>:9443/oauth2/token
```

Errors am getting in docker console while trying to login using username 'devtest7@mailinator.com' :

[image]

**Things to note :**

- WSO2 AM version is **2.1.0** , WSO2 IS version is **5.3.0**
- Arguments(headers & parameters) for the request is the same as that
  used earlier(except the username and password).
- I am able to create a new users and the corresponding user is listed
  in Carbondb users list.
- The issue exists while trying to login using existing user as well as
  newly created users.
- I have recently generated new ssl certificate for the application.
- Able to login using super admin only . Login using newly created email and username is not working.

I tried solutions seen on stackoverflow which doesn't fixed my issues. Can any one please help?

Comment: Have you enabled email user name in API Manager?

Comment: My carbon, publisher and store usernames are not email addresses. I tried enabling email username from apimanager . But on enabling that, I was not able to login to carbon and publisher. Without publishing the apis the webapp won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who commented and tried to figure out the solution for the issue i mentioned. I got the resolution for the issue . As  i tried multiple times to login by doing permutations and combinations in configurations, authentication was blocked for me. As a reason, i couldn't login and generate access token . I was able to resolve it by changing a flag in *identity.xml* file inside **IS** . 
Changed the UserOperationEventListener enabling from 'true' to 'false' .

Before:

```
<EventListener enable="true" name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener" orderId="95" type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener"/>
```

After:

```
<EventListener enable="false" name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener" orderId="95" type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener"/>
```

This change allowed me to block the invalid authentication check. We are anyway adding that check from our code side.

Answer (score 1):

There is a line in the above logs saying that SP tenant is not equal to user tenant and SP is not SaaS. Are the SP and users are from different tenants? Normally users cannot access SP across different tenants.

If you want to make the SP accessible across different tenants then you need to enable SaaS application option in the SP. Check this doc to learn more about SaaS application https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider

Comment: It seems piraveena is correct.  However, if you follow doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username, you can avoid the need for adding @carbon.super at the end of username for super tenant

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, it says

> Non-SaaS service Provider's tenant domain is not same as user tenant
>   domain; carbon.super != mailinator.com

From the logs, the SP's is in the **carbon.super** tenant. But it considers the user as in the tenant **mailinator.com**.

When we specify the username for password grant with email as username, we have to use the full username with the tenant domain. (**devtest7@mailinator.com@carbon.super**).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was also thinking about that and was looking for solutions. Later on found out that the main issue was due to a flag which was causing the issue in identity.xml inside IS. Changed the enabling from 'true' to 'false' . 

`<EventListener enable="false"
            name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener"
            orderId="95" type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener"/>`